# Slow MS Access Query (Using DSum & DCount Functions)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm having an issue in Microsoft Access where my query calculates extremely slow (it takes hours and hours). This query is reading a table that has 150,000 records and each record belongs to one of 4,000 unique groups (called *API_10*).

The goal of the query is to calculate a running cumulative production value (organized by *API_10* and *Date*) such that the running cumulative production starts over at each new *API_10* group. Each record in the table has a field called *No* which is an autonumber that MS Access calculates so that the table has a Primary Key. An example of what I'm describing is shown below:

**MyTable:**

```
No     API_10       Date           Production
1      1            1/1/2010       1000
2      1            2/1/2010       500
3      2            7/1/2014       300
4      2            8/1/2014       400
```

**MyQuery:**

```
No       API_10         Date              Production   Cumulative_Production
1        1              11/1/2010         1000         1000
2        1              12/1/2010         500          1500
3        2              27/1/2014         300          300
4        2              28/1/2014         400          700
```

Here is a sample of the code (typed in the Expression Builder on MS Access) used to create the *Cumulative_Production* column in *MyQuery*:

**Cumulative_Production:**

```
DSum("[Production]","[MyTable]","[API_10]='" & [API_10] & "' AND [No]<=" & [No])
```

Do note that this is a simplified version of the actual query/table. The real query also computes another field called *Normalized_Prod_Month* which counts the number of production dates (starting at 1) for each unique *API_10* as shown below:

**NORMALIZED_PROD_MONTH:**

```
DCount("[Date]","[MyTable]","[API_10]='" & [API_10] & "' AND [No]<=" & [No])
```

Any tips for improving these types of calculations would greatly help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you apply this query to each record, then you must access `n * (n + 1) / 2` records. If all 4000 groups have about the same size of 38 records, you get `4000 * 38 * (38 + 1) / 2 = ~ 3 Mio` accesses. But this is the best case, since larger groups have an over-proportional cost because of the quadratic nature of `n * (n + 1) / 2`.

You are better off by creating the running sum in a loop in VBA, and accessing each record only once.

```vb
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim lastNoApi As Long, runningSum As Long

Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY NoAPI_10, Date")
Do Until rs.EOF
    If rs!NoAPI_10 <> lastNoApi Then
       runningSum = 0 
       lastNoApi = rs!NoAPI_10
    End If
    runningSum = runningSum + rs!Production

    'TODO: insert the result into a temporary table

    rs.MoveNext
Loop
rs.Close: Set rs = Nothing
db.Close: Set db = Nothing
```

Or use the following query. It still has a quadratic cost, but a single query is always more performing than multiple calls to `DCount`, `DSum` or `DLookup`.

```sql
SELECT
    A.API_10,
    A.Date,
    A.Production,
    (Select Sum(B.Production)
     FROM MyTable B
     WHERE B.API_10 = A.API_10 And B.[No] <= A.[No]) AS Cumulative_Production
FROM MyTable AS A
ORDER BY A.API_10, A.Date;
```

Assuming that the `No` column is consistent with the date sequence. If the dates are unique, you can also replace `B.[No] <= A.[No]` with `B.[Date] <= A.[Date]`.

Comment: I am a bit confused by the A.NoAPI_10. These should be two separate fields in the table. No is the Autonumber field and API_10 is the group

Comment: Ok, your question was badly formatted and there was no space between these two columns, so I thought there was on column `NoAPI_10`. Changed the query now.